# Open a new window and pass parameters to it vb.net asp

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reporting

Hi I have a web app which has a listbox of all the available reports for a particular user. I want to open a new page 'ReportViewerPane' when a row is clicked and pass the report name and some parameters through to the reportviewer.aspx I then need to set the ReportViewer controls .reportpath to the correct (passed through) value and set the parameters values (also passed through).

I the moment I have this in the parent page. 'PassParmString' is a textbox on the main form:

```
function open_win()
{
   var Parms = document.getElementById('<%=PassParmString.ClientID %>');
   window.open("ViewerPane.aspx?prm=" + Parms,"_blank","left=20,top=20,width=1000,height=1140,toolbar=0,resizable=1");
}
</script>
```

but have no idea how to access the parameter `'Parms'` that I pass once I am in in the ReportViewer.aspx form.

Please help.

I'm not good at this. And really trying to understand the posts so please be patient.

Many thanks

Mac

Comment: @ andrew Mark the post as answer whichever answer helped you. just click on the right sign in front of the answer which helped you. it will help our fellow peers to go for the right approach. as a SO QA user it should be our responsibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get it using regular request querystring collection in your `ViewerPane.aspx` page

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) 
    If NOT IsPostBack
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("prm"))
           string querystringvalue = Request.QueryString("prm").ToString()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

try changing your javascript to this

```
<script>
function open_win()
{
   var Parms = document.getElementById('<%=PassParmString.ClientID %>');
   window.open("ViewerPane.aspx?prm=" + Parms.value,"_blank","left=20,top=20,width=1000,height=1140,toolbar=0,resizable=1");
}
</script>
```

See if this helps :)

Comment: Still not. It is passing NULL so I assume the fault lies in the Javascript where I define and pass it. Still struggling ...

Comment: @AndrewMcLintock yes you should give a check whether your
 
var Parms = document.getElementById('<%=PassParmString.ClientID %>');

BTW is PassParmString a HiddenField or what 
evaluating or not use 
alert(document.getElementById('<%=PassParmString.ClientID %>'));
To check in javascript

Comment: try this in javascript
Parms = document.getElementById('PassParmString').value;

as @brizz suggested

Answer (score 1):

u are passing the element, and not its value, u can do something like this :

```
Parms = document.getElementById('PassParmString').value;
```

Comment: Thanks guys for all your input. It works - IT BLOOMING WORKS (and I am bald!)