# Set SelectParameter for SqlDataSource SelectCommand with unknown number of variables

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="workHourListSqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PlaningSystemConnectionString %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT *
                    FROM Date AS t1 FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM WorkHoursEntry WHERE (WorkerID LIKE @WorkerID)) AS t2 ON t1.PKDate = t2.WorkDay 
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN Worker AS t3 ON t2.WorkerID = t3.WorkerID 
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Project WHERE ProjectID IN(@Project)) AS t4 ON t2.ProjectID = t4.ProjectID"
     FilterExpression="YearMonth IN({0})">
     <FilterParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="yearMonthFilterLabel" Name="YearMonth" 
                    PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
     </FilterParameters>
     <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="WorkerIDLabel" Name="WorkerID" 
                    PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="projectFilterLabel" Name="Project" 
                    PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Greetings, I have problem with @Project ControlParameter, problem is I don't know how to pass several values and FilterParameters method won't work as I want. Is there any way to pass several variables ?  (without using c#).

```
projectFilterLabel.Text = 'aaa, bbb, ccc';
```

Basically what I want to do is to select all values from Date table and join them with some values from Project table and output to DataList.

Any help appreciated, I just started learning asp.net

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your asp form create a javascript function to handle the Opening of the window fro your report. In this function set a parameters (var pPassParm) value to a textbox.text (hidden on your parent form) and pass this value with opening of the window  ( /reportfolder/report.asx?pPassparm )

On your execution code, create a piece of code that concatenates all your parameters into one string ( textbox.text = 'StartDate = 2012/01/01, EndDate = 2012/02/01, Surname = Jones' etc) before opening the new form for the report.

Refer to post [Open a new window and pass parameters to it vb.net asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224407/open-a-new-window-and-pass-parameters-to-it-vb-net-asp)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating new querys with parameters inside (replacing older ones) for SqlDataSource on events.